# Non-explicit function returning in scala

Tags: scala, function, functional-programming

I am pretty new to `Scala/Functional programing` ,and i am trying to figure out how to write a `function` that will return an function(not explicitly said that it will be function called getSometing) ,but only by set of parameters ,so basically i want to rewrite this

```
def plusTwo(nr : Int) : Int={
    nr + 2
}

def getAlgorythm(algoName : String) = (plusTwo : Int)=>{
     algoName match{
          case "plusTwo" => plusTwo
     }
}
```

To someting like this

```
  def plusTwo(nr : Int) : Int={
       nr + 2
  }

  def square(nr : Int) : Int{
          nr * nr
  }

  def getAlgorythm(algoName : String) = (someFunctionThatTakesIntParam: Int)=>{
            algoName match{
              case "plusTwo" => plusTwo
              case "square" => square
            }
        }
```

Is this non-explicit form of syntax somehow possible in `Scala` ? I think it should be some way, in some level this is like signing different implementations to common interface.

I am pointing here to posibility ,that if this is posible in Scala,it can be way to avoid awesome amount of reflection calls,specialy with Gui frameworks,while you are binding data.

Comment: Could you rephrase `(not explicitly said that it will be function called getSometing) ,but only by set of parameters ,so basically i want to rewrite this`?

Comment: You just get the syntax wrong. `def getAlg(name: String): Int => Int = { ... }` should do what you want

Comment: Not sure what/how you are trying whatever you want, but if you add `=` in your `square` method like `def square(...) = { ... }` , it should work.

Comment: What i mean is, if this will be writer in Java, the getAlgorythm will be a method returning a type Method,that will be switched by String parameter,for example a method name,and with reflection i will be able to get that method. In Scala,where there is a posibillity of returning functions, i want to do the same thing,but with avoiding an use of reflections. So what should be done is that i type getAlgorythm("square") and the function will return an function what is implementing a square algorythm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will rewrite your code in slightly cleaner style and add some fixes:

```
def plusTwo(nr : Int) : Int = nr + 2
def square(nr : Int) : Int = nr * nr

def getAlgorithm(algoName : String) = 
  algoName match{
    case "plusTwo" => plusTwo _
    case "square" => square _
  }
```

- `Algorithm` is spelled with `i` in English
- The `square` method needs an `=` in its defintion
- `plusTwo` and `square` are *methods*, not *functions*: this may be a bit confusing, but these are different constructions in Scala. Often Scala tries to blur this distinction, but unfortunately this is not one of these cases,
- so, in the places we'd want to treat these methods as *functions* we need to postfix them with an `_`, which when used after a method call instructs the compiler to transform methods into functions.

To further clarify the distinction between methods and functions let's make another implementation:

```
val plusTwo: Int => Int = nr => nr + 2
val square = (nr: Int) => nr * nr

def getAlgorythm(algoName : String) = 
  algoName match{
    case "plusTwo" => plusTwo
    case "square" => square
  }
```

- Now, the two methods and not methods anymore, they are vals, both of type `Int => Int`, in other words, functions! No need to use `_` this time.

Comment: Thanks,the first case is what i was basicaly looking for :)